# How to change pythons response to a string input in a int(input('Q1')), to a looped Q?

Tags: python, input, while-loop, int

My problem is that for example when I type

```
x = int(input('whats 1+1')
```

if someone jokingly types a string such as 'two' or '2' python auto-crashes, is there any way to instead make python, tell the person to enter it as an integer and then using a while loop, repeat the question until they do. thnx in advance :)

btw the variable (x) has to be an integer, when being input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_int(prompt="Enter an Integer:"):
    while True:
        try:
           return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
           print("That is not an integer!")

x = get_int("What is 1+1")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_integer():  # Define a function to make things easier
    while True:  # Keep looping, until we return from the function
        x = input('What is 1 + 1?')  # ask for input
        try:
            x = int(x)  # can we convert it to an integer?
        except (ValueError, TypeError):  # None or 'hello' would fail
            print('Invalid entry, please try again!')
        else:  # no exception!
            print('x was good!')
            return x  # exit our function

value = get_integer()  # Call our function
```

Comment: with this method you could also use LBYL and `if x.strip().isdigit(): return int(x)`

Comment: @Joran Trying to keep things very explicit for the sake of understanding, but yes your answer is succinct(er?). Today I learned: LBYL == Look Before You Leap!

Comment: can you actually get a TypeError? is that even possible? (ie is there some instance where input returns None?)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I doubt it. However in most cases when I use `int(var)` I so frequently run into issues with 'None' that I figured I'd throw it in there.

Comment: ilke444 Says: @Joran Since input(prompt) is converted to eval(raw_input(prompt)), and eval can easily return None, then you can actually get a TypeError.

Comment: to which the reply is @ilke444 this is python3 ... in python3 `input` replaced `raw_input`